# Facing some problems in sqoop-export?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have exported many times tables from Hive to SQL Server. I never face this problem.

I have use field delimiter as "," and also created a table in SQL Server.

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1/bin$ ./sqoop-export --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.1;username=abcd;password=12345;database=HadoopTest' --table tmptempmeasurereport --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tmptempmeasurereport

12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory: Using Microsoft's SQL Server - Hadoop Connector
12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tmptempmeasurereport]
12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tmptempmeasurereport]
12/03/29 16:20:21 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2
12/03/29 16:20:22 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/1c5aae88cd7daca66aa665d4bab5b470/tmptempmeasurereport.jar
12/03/29 16:20:22 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of tmptempmeasurereport
12/03/29 16:20:22 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tmptempmeasurereport]
12/03/29 16:20:22 WARN mapreduce.ExportJobBase: IOException checking SequenceFile header: java.io.EOFException
12/03/29 16:20:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/03/29 16:20:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/03/29 16:20:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201203291108_0645
12/03/29 16:20:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/03/29 16:20:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203291108_0645_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:350)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.__loadFromFields(tmptempmeasurereport.java:383)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.parse(tmptempmeasurereport.java:332)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)

12/03/29 16:20:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203291108_0645_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:350)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.__loadFromFields(tmptempmeasurereport.java:383)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.parse(tmptempmeasurereport.java:332)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)

12/03/29 16:20:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203291108_0645_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:350)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.__loadFromFields(tmptempmeasurereport.java:383)
    at tmptempmeasurereport.parse(tmptempmeasurereport.java:332)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)

12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201203291108_0645
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=18742
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 21.0326 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
12/03/29 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
12/03/29 16:20:43 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
```

[My vesion is as- hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3,
sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1,
hive-0.7.1]

Did I do something wrong.? Pls help me out from this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to export data from an external hive table?

Comment: @WR10: yes. I am using external table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to add **--fields-terminated-by** and **--lines-terminated-by** option in the sqoop command.

Comment: @user1073129: Your external table in hive doesn't actually store the data in your hdfs directory /user/hive/warehouse/tmptempmeasurereport . So sqoop is not able to find the files in the directory. For exporting hive external tables, you first need to execute "insert overwrite directory {give the hdfs path here} " option to select the data from the table. By this the data from your external table is copied to the given hdfs directory . Then you can run the sqoop job giving this path. Or else you can export the data by giving the path of the data given when creating the external table.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error if the table I am exporting into has additional columns which do not exist in the file. If you examine the auto-generated `tmptempmeasurereport.java`, you will see the logic Sqoop is using.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by deleting `\n` at the end of the last record in the text input file.

- `"1,this,42\n2,that,100\n"` - fails
- `"1,this,42\n2,that,100"` - works